# C# ClickOnce disappeared files from AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

Recently, files have been deleted from clients from the installation folder AppData\Local\Apps\2.0...
**Only one folder remains, example**
`> C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3BWNG62B.Y4Y\LJMH1C5Z.ONJ\manifests`
and folder LJMH1C5Z.ONJ is clean

Our program is installed on several hundred computers and at the moment 20 have already had such a problem. Moreover, some did not update our program for several months, but the folder was also cleared in same days.
It feels like windows somehow updated and began to clean the folder. But we can't find a solution yet, maybe someone knows?

We tried reinstalling the program, but everything repeats chaotically

We noticed that everyone has the kb5029244 Windows update installed

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the Windows update kb5029244

Now ClickOnce applications must be signed only with a real certificate (Code Signing)